# How can I Hide Gnome3 shell extension at the top?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I have installed the "simple net speed" gnome-extensions, but I want to hide it from top panel, In the tweak tool, under extensions, I do not see any option for the extention, Is that also by design?

[image]

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04,Gnome 3.28.1,tweak tool installed.

Comment: what happens when you right click the icon?

Comment: nothing happened, i tried.

Comment: Rather than right click as @JoshuaBesneatte sugggests perhaps try **left click** instead?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Best screen name EVER!

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Ironically I haven't booted Windows 10 in months but right now I'm typing in it whilst 82% through download of Redstone 4 (April 2018 spring creators) update :D I do have Ubuntu Bash on Windows screen (WSL) open too though ;)

Answer (score 2):

That is the feature this extension provides, i.e. it places an indicator in top bar which shows network speed. You can left click on the icon to switch between various modes:

> 1. Total net speed in bits per second
> 2. Total net speed in Bytes per second
> 3. Up & down speed in bits per second
> 4. Up & down speed in Bytes per second
> 5. Total of downloaded in Bytes (Right click to reset counter)

If you simply want to get rid of it, toggle it off in Tweaks:

[image]

Comment: doesn't this just disable it? I think user wants to just hide it from the panel or configure it....

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte The extension just puts an indicator in top bar and the user wants to hide the indicator, so what's the difference from disabling it? (unless I'm missing something very obvious)

Comment: yea, good point... I just mentioned because his tweak screenshot is exactly the same as yours....

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte I copied from it :-p

Comment: LOL... I guess that would explain that!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want **Net Speed** in the systray and are open to considering another option, might I suggest `conky`? It's a light weight system monitor that is highly configurable and immensely popular. You can almost say it has a cult following:

[image: Conky Network.gif]

Near the bottom is a real time display of network speed including graphs. Also `vnstat` is used to list total network traffic for today, yesterday, this week and this month. You can set the month to your ISP's billing cycle, ie April 16 to May 16.

To install conky use:

```
sudo apt install conky
```

To find a plethora of custom setups for `conky` see [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865).